# What are the origins of Vermin Lord?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-3e, prestige-class, lore

### What exactly is the origin of vermin lord?

[image: 1]]

Vermin Lord are spellcasters who focus on the use of vermin, slightly turning into one of them by developing insectoid wings and chitinous plates. I have tried, but I couldn't find the origin of this idea. Was there a myth, a book or a movie?

Comment: The second image doesn't appear to be of a vermin lord. Is there any particular reason it's there?

Comment: Are you asking where D&D got the idea, what the earliest known instance of this sort of character is in any medium, or...?

Comment: Okey, i skipped the mention in other systems and focused the question on d&d only.

Answer (score 2):

Like most everything else in fantasy, the concept of a vermin commander comes from fiction, mythology, and religion. The pied piper of Hamlin, for an example. Or arguably the plague of frogs or locusts in the Bible. This is not exactly a unique concept.